# Prolog: Is there a way to find the longest consecutive number sequence in a list and get its length?

Tags: prolog

Given a list of 5 random natural numbers (the number's range is from 1 to 13), i.e. [1,6,11,12,13], how can I find out the longest consecutive number sequence (i.e. [11,12,13]) that its length must be larger or equal to 3, and also get its length?

Comment: For example, if the input is [1,6,11,12,13], then the output would be 3.
If the input is [1,7,8,9,10], then the output would be 4.

Comment: And again, The sequence must be larger or equal to 3. [1,2,4,5,8] would return 0. Any thoughts are welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse the list keeping track of the current sequence and its length along with the maximum sequence and length found so far.

After processing all the list you can check whether the maximum length is >= 3 and select the proper output:

```
longest_sequence([First|L], Len1, Seq) :-
    longest_sequence(L, 1, [First], 0, [], Len, RSeq),
    (   Len>=3
    ->  reverse(RSeq, Seq),
        Len1=Len
    ;   Seq=[],
        Len1=0
    ).
  
longest_sequence([], CurLen, CurSeq, MaxLen, MaxSeq, Len, Seq):-
  (CurLen > MaxLen -> Len-Seq=CurLen-CurSeq ; Len-Seq=MaxLen-MaxSeq).
longest_sequence([CurItem|L], CurLen, [LastItem|CurSeq], MaxLen, MaxSeq, Len, Seq):-
  (
   succ(LastItem, CurItem) ->
    (
      succ(CurLen, CurLen1),
      CurSeq1=[CurItem,LastItem|CurSeq],
      MaxLen1-MaxSeq1=MaxLen-MaxSeq
    ) ;
    (
      (CurLen > MaxLen -> MaxLen1-MaxSeq1=CurLen-[LastItem|CurSeq] ; MaxLen1-MaxSeq1=MaxLen-MaxSeq),
      CurLen1=1,
      CurSeq1=[CurItem]
    )
   ),
   longest_sequence(L, CurLen1, CurSeq1, MaxLen1, MaxSeq1, Len, Seq).
```

Sample runs:

```
?- longest_sequence([1,6,11,12,13], Len, Seq).
Len = 3,
Seq = [11, 12, 13].

?- longest_sequence([1,6,11,12,13,2,3,4,5], Len, Seq).
Len = 4,
Seq = [2, 3, 4, 5].

?- longest_sequence([1,2], Len, Seq).
Len = 0,
Seq = [].
```

Comment: Jeez mate you are my saviour! It's pretty late here, I will read the code carefully tomorrow!

Comment: Oh man I think u misunderstood. First the length of the given list is locked to 5, and something like [7,7,8,8,9] is going to return 3 because there elements in the list can form [7,8,9], so the order of elements in the original list doesn't matter as long as some elements in the list can form a consecutive sequence longer than or equal to 3.

Comment: By the way, actually you don't need to return the sequence you found, just return the length of the longest sequence would be enough.

Comment: In addition, you can suppose the input list is always sorted using msort.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding. I gave poor examples.

Comment: No worries man I think I just solved it! Just wrote a function to remove duplicates in the list and then we're good!

Answer (score -1):

```
def longestSeq(n):
    seqMax = 0
    counter = 0
    i = 0
    while i+1 < len(n):
        curr = n[i+1]
        last = n[i]

        
        sub = curr - last

        if sub == 1:
            if counter == 0:
                counter = 2 
            else:
                counter += 1 
        else:
            if counter > 0:
               if seqMax < counter:
                   seqMax = counter
                   counter = 0 
        i += 1 

    if seqMax < counter:
        seqMax = counter

    if seqMax >= 3:
        return seqMax
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: if in your code you have to account for the fact each element falls between 1 and 13 you simply have to add the condition for it which should be pretty basic

Comment: Sorry mate but this is a prolog task...

Comment: jesuss my bad man.

Comment: All good mate thanks for contribution!